# FileReference TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In my Form, I have a **TextInput** and a **FileReference** with Browse Button. In this form, when I submit without selecting any image file it will throw an error like this "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

My need:
If I submit the form without selecting any image file, it has to be take a dummy image programmatically. I don't have any idea about it.

My sample code:

```
        <s:Form id="mainForm" height="100%" width="100%" left="10%" right="10%" top="10%">
            <s:FormItem id="nameLabel" label="Employee Name">
                <s:TextInput id="employeeName" rollOver="validateAndSubmit()"/>
            </s:FormItem> 
            <s:FormItem id="imageLabel" label="Image">
                <mx:HBox>
                    <s:TextInput id="employeeImageName" editable="false" showErrorSkin="true" showErrorTip="false"/>
                    <s:Button id="imageButton" label="Browse" click="onBrowseButtonClicked(event)"/>
                </mx:HBox >
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem>
                <s:layout>
                    <s:HorizontalLayout gap="10"/>
                </s:layout>
                <s:Button id="submitButton" label="Submit" click="storeInputs(event)"/>
                <s:Button id="clearButton" label="clear" click="clearInputs()"/>
            </s:FormItem>
        </s:Form>
        <s:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{arrayCollection}">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" />
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Employee" id="imageColumn" dataField="imageData"/>
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>                                    
                            <s:Image id="image"  source="{data.imageData}"  visible="true" height="80" width="100"/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
```

The storeInput()

```
        private function storeInputs(event:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            arrayCollection.addItem({
                name : employeeName.text, 
                imageData: loadFile.data
            });
        }
```

**Edit:**
My onBrowseButtonClicked() code:

```
        public var loadFile:FileReference; 
        [Bindable]private var arrayCollection : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection ();

        private function onBrowseButtonClicked(event : MouseEvent) : void
        {
            loadFile = new FileReference();

            loadFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images: (*.jpeg, *.jpg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.gif; *.png");
            loadFile.browse([fileFilter]);
        }

        private function selectHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            loadFile.load();    
        }
```

If I doesn't select any file using the **Browse** Button, it has to be load a dummy image automatically. How can I do it?

Comment: At which timepoint do you call the function?

Comment: Where is defined "loadFile"?

Comment: Can you get a stack trace of the error,then you will know where your problem is, (it should give you the line number)

Comment: The error will be occurred in this line "imageData: loadFile.data", when I submit without selecting any image file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make it your Image tag as itemRenderer like this

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Employee" id="imageColumn" dataField="imageData" itemRenderer="components.GridItemRender"/>
```

And the GridItemRender.MXML

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[           
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;         

        protected function emp_renderHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            if (data.imageData == null)
            {
                image.source = "http://localhost/demo/images/male.jpg";
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image id="image"  source="{data.imageData}"  width="80" height="100" render="emp_renderHandler(event)"/>
```

I think this code may help you...

Answer (score 0):

you need something like that: you may need to change error event type, i was used e:IOErrorEvent for my URLLoader object, but i'm not sure it works for your situation

```
private function selectHandler(event:Event):void
{
   try
   {

      loadFile.load();

   } catch (e:Error)
      {
         loadFile = dummypicture;
         loadFile.load();
      }
}
```

Comment: My dummy image like this"localhost/images/male.jpg". How can I assign this to loadFile?

Comment: You can use "URLLoader" to load it...(need some more functions) Or you can "embed" it to your project. (easy, but you have to recompile project to change this dummy picture when you need)

Comment: could you please add the sample code? Because I don't know how can I assign a URLLoader to Filereference.

Comment: yes i can, but i don't, first you should try to follow the official & unofficial docs about that on the internet... that's pretty easy stuff...

Comment: Simple buddy check for the data.image is null or not. If null then embed a default image in your project & assign the path instead data.image.

Comment: Thank you so much RIA Dev.I have done it based on your guide.